# How to organize many-to-many relations with additional relationship: hasMany for interception table

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I have table users and table channels.User can subscribe to channels and unsubscribe many times. 
The task: I need to store all subscription and unsubscription dates for each channel. What the best way to do this in Laravel 5?

I have an idea to store this dates as array 
like:

```
[['subscribe' => date, 'unsubscribe' => date], ...]
```

in intersection table(users_channels) field, but is this a best solution?

And i have an idea to store this date to additional table, but how to create and update this table fields. The only thing that is convenient in this case - is to get all subscription and unsabscribtion dates for user in some channel with hasManyThrough () function

Comment: Their are so many options on eloquent to do this , check touchParent/Child or postSave methods or you can event write events on Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5 has Observers, you can check documentation here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#observers.

You can also use Events.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events

You can check the upcoming information and based on that add subscription trail in database.